# Function sec.axis doesn't show the bars of the second variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I have to compute a plot with 2 bars for each x observation.
y1 is a variable that can assume large values (also hundreds of thousands)
y2 is in the range [0, 100].
I have reported an example with fictitious data.
The problem is that y1 is okay, but y2 is plotted with reference to the first axis values instead of the second one (and so it's pratically invisible).

```
library(tidyverse)

data = data.frame("x" = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"), 
                  "y1" = c(10000, 70000, 120000, 75000, 500, 2000, 10000, 18000),
                  "y2" = c(22, 30, 36, 10, 1, 80, 33, 39))

data %>%
  gather("Type", "Value", -x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, Value, fill = Type))+
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity")+
  scale_y_continuous(name = "First axis",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./1000, name = "Second axis"))
```

Moreover, it would be good limiting the y2 axis to 100.

Answer (score 1):

Simply applying a transformation in `sec_axis` isn't sufficient. You also have to rescale the data for which I added a `mutate` step. To get a max range for the secondary axis you have to adjust the scaling, i.e. for your example data `1250` works.

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(y2 = y2 * 1250) %>%
  gather("Type", "Value", -x) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, Value, fill = Type)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "First axis",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 1250, name = "Second axis")
  )
```

[image]